# Design of 100W class a MOSFET power amplifer

Tags: circuit-design, analog, power-electronics

Id like to design a 100W class a MOSFET power amplifier. For my application I have a 8.33 ohm load and a +15 V to 0 V supply voltage range. I'd like the voltage across the output resistor to be adjustable within a +/- 1 V range of 12 V.

My first instinct has been to use a common source amplifier using a PSMN3R430BLE MOSFET. My attempt at calculating the source resistance is as follows:

[image: Calculations for source resistance]

With this as a reference circuit:

[image: Reference common source amplifier circuit]

One problem I am aware of is the variable K. I haven't been able to find a suitable way of calculating this value based on the datasheet of the MOSFET. When trying to read the g_m value from the drain current vs gate-source voltage plot of the datasheet (Fig 9 on page 8) I get a transconductance value of approximately 100 which seems way too high to me. [Datasheet for the specified MOSFET](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN3R4-30BL.pdf)

The gain and therefore input side of the amplifier isn't super important as I'll need to use some opamps to generate the signal with a DC offset from a MCUs PWM channel.

Comment: Even if you applied the full 15 volts from your DC supply to the 8.33 ohm load, the power is only 27 watts and a mile off being 100 watts.

Comment: Amplifier for what? Which frequency range? Plus you need about 29V into 8.33 ohms to get 100W so why the 100W requirement?

Comment: Your mosfet is for switching. You’re likely to exceed its SOA specs running Class A.

Comment: @Andyaka youre right i accidentally specified the wrong load. it was meant to be 1.44Ohms for 100W at 12V

Comment: @Justme As mentioned in the comment replying to Andy aka i specified the wrong load resistance. As for frequency range i just need to be able to control the output voltage so its stable using feedback to a MCU for control.

Comment: @Kartman Ill go searching for a more suitible mosfet and redo my calculations based on that.

Comment: `Which frequency range?` @MalteGardøSteensen

Comment: @Andyaka Dont have any definite limits for it since its supposed to be part of a stable steadystate control loop. Lets go with a conservative 1k bandwidth

Comment: What is the purpose of this amplifier?  Audio, instrumentation, broadcasting, ...?

Comment: I wonder if a [class >= D amp](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html) could be used instead?  To not waste more than half of that power as heat.